# Unity3D, have BOTH 3D and UI Raycaster simultaneously respond to touch?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch, unity3d-ui

These days in Unity you very easily detect touch on objects using a raycaster...

```
public class DragThreeDee:MonoBehaviour,IPointerDownHandler
       IPointerUpHandler, IBeginDragHandler,
       IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler
       {
       public void OnPointerDown (PointerEventData data)
          { etc
```

So, regarding your UI layer, it correctly ignores touch on the UI layer and so on.

What if you want the following to happen,

you want to collect (simultaneously, in the same frame, both) a touch which is over both a 3D object, and, a UI item?

(Imagine you have, say, a few transparent UI buttons on the screen; you also have ordinary 3D robots running around. User clicks on a point on the screen where there's a UI button, and "underneath", a robot.  BOTH the robot's script as above, and the button, should respond.)

How would you do that?  I tried extensively using separate cameras, separate `EventSystem`, adjusting the layers, blocking masks and so on.  I can't find a way to do it.

How to do this in Unity?

Comment: I'm afraid this is built in functionality in StandaloneInputModule. Seems like if any of the GraphicRaycasters return a hit than PhysicsRaycaster is not checked. You can try to override StandaloneInuputModule I guess :/

Comment: Hi @NikaKasradze - - - fascinating, it looks like you have hit the nail on the head.  Very interesting ...

Comment: Please post an answer if you find a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks complicated but can be done.

**1**.Route the data from `PointerEventData` in all of the UI components you want to unblock 3D GameObjects raycast on.

**2**.Get all the instance of `PhysicsRaycaster` with `FindObjectsOfType<PhysicsRaycaster>()`. In terms of performance, it would make sense to cache this.

**3**.Perform a Raycast with `PhysicsRaycaster.Raycast` which will return all GameObjects with Collider attached to it.

**4**.Use `ExecuteEvents.Execute` to send the appropriate event to the result stored in the `RaycastResult`.

*`RaycastForwarder`* script:

```
public class RaycastForwarder : MonoBehaviour
{
    List<PhysicsRaycaster> rayCast3D = new List<PhysicsRaycaster>();
    List<RaycastResult> rayCast3DResult = new List<RaycastResult>();

    private static RaycastForwarder localInstance;
    public static RaycastForwarder Instance { get { return localInstance; } }


    private void Awake()
    {
        if (localInstance != null && localInstance != this)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            localInstance = this;
        }
    }

    public void notifyPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        findColliders(eventData, PointerEventType.Down);
    }

    public void notifyPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        findColliders(eventData, PointerEventType.Up);
    }

    public void notifyPointerDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        findColliders(eventData, PointerEventType.Drag);
    }

    private void findColliders(PointerEventData eventData, PointerEventType evType)
    {
        UpdateRaycaster();

        //Loop Through All Normal Collider(3D/Mesh Renderer) and throw Raycast to each one
        for (int i = 0; i < rayCast3D.Count; i++)
        {
            //Send Raycast to all GameObject with 3D Collider
            rayCast3D[i].Raycast(eventData, rayCast3DResult);
            sendRayCast(eventData, evType);
        }
        //Reset Result
        rayCast3DResult.Clear();
    }

    private void sendRayCast(PointerEventData eventData, PointerEventType evType)
    {
        //Loop over the RaycastResult and simulate the pointer event
        for (int i = 0; i < rayCast3DResult.Count; i++)
        {
            GameObject target = rayCast3DResult[i].gameObject;
            PointerEventData evData = createEventData(rayCast3DResult[i]);

            if (evType == PointerEventType.Drag)
            {
                ExecuteEvents.Execute<IDragHandler>(target,
                                        evData,
                                        ExecuteEvents.dragHandler);
            }

            if (evType == PointerEventType.Down)
            {
                ExecuteEvents.Execute<IPointerDownHandler>(target,
                               evData,
                               ExecuteEvents.pointerDownHandler);
            }

            if (evType == PointerEventType.Up)
            {
                ExecuteEvents.Execute<IPointerUpHandler>(target,
                    evData,
                    ExecuteEvents.pointerUpHandler);
            }
        }
    }

    private PointerEventData createEventData(RaycastResult rayResult)
    {
        PointerEventData evData = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);
        evData.pointerCurrentRaycast = rayResult;
        return evData;
    }

    //Get all PhysicsRaycaster in the scene
    private void UpdateRaycaster()
    {
        convertToList(FindObjectsOfType<PhysicsRaycaster>(), rayCast3D);
    }

    private void convertToList(PhysicsRaycaster[] fromComponent, List<PhysicsRaycaster> toComponent)
    {
        //Clear and copy new Data
        toComponent.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < fromComponent.Length; i++)
        {
            toComponent.Add(fromComponent[i]);
        }
    }

    public enum PointerEventType
    {
        Drag, Down, Up
    }
}
```

*`RayCastRouter`* script:

```
public class RayCastRouter : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler,
       IPointerUpHandler,
       IDragHandler
{
    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        RaycastForwarder.Instance.notifyPointerDrag(eventData);
    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        RaycastForwarder.Instance.notifyPointerDown(eventData);
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        RaycastForwarder.Instance.notifyPointerUp(eventData);
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

**A**.Attach `RaycastForwarder` to an empty GameObject.

**B**.Attach `RayCastRouter` to any UI component such as Image that you don't want to block a 3D GameObject. That's it. Any UI component with `RayCastRouter` attached to it will be able to allow a 3D GameObject behind it receive a raycast.

An event will now be sent to 3D Object that has a script that implements functions from `IPointerDownHandler`, `IPointerUpHandler` and `IDragHandler` interface.

Don't forget to attach *`Physics Raycaster`* to the camera.

Comment: Wow - checking this out!

Comment: Almost all of the answers I provided in your question few hours ago requires forwarding the events. I tested this one for over a day and this one seems to have no bug at-all. Let me know if you see a bug in it.